# Split sentences based on dots without being trapped by words like Dr., Mr., etc

Tags: php, regex

I want to split a text into sentences using fullstops like '.' . But if words like 'Dr.', 'Mrs.', 'U.S.A.', etc. exist in the text, then the splitter may get confused. For example, consider the following text:

Mr. Bean is a British comedy television series.

This splits into two sentences:
1: Mr.
2: Bean is a British comedy television series.

Is there a smart way to solve this problem in PHP without using a dictionary/array of such special words?

BTW, I have used the following code to check whether a given word has fullstop or not. This code works fine but I need to fill up the dictionary/array with lots of such words. I am looking for a solution that doesn't need any dictionary. Now, any idea?

```
public function doesWordHasFullstop($word){
if(in_array(strtolower(trim($word)), array('dr.','mr.','mrs.','prof.','ms.','sr.','jr.','m.sc.'
                              ,'b.sc.','ph.d.','st.', 'gen.','sen.','rep.','jan.',
                              'feb.','mar.', 'apr.','jun.','jul.','aug.','sep.',
                              'oct.','nov.','dec.','drs.','m.d.','b.a.','m.a.','d.d.s.',
                              'u.s.a','u.a.e','u.k.','p.m.','a.m.'))){
    return FALSE;
}
preg_match('/[.,;):>\]?!@#|]+/', $word, $matches);
if(count($matches)>0){
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

}

Comment: The only other option would be a grammatical analyser, which is obviously even more complicated and still requires some form of dictionary.

Comment: PHP does not understanf English and it certainly does not know pop culture. that's what it would take to parse that sentence as you intend.

Comment: I agree with @JorgeCampos - [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  Give us a [Short, Self Contained, Compileable Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Without an exception dictionary, you'll need to do some assumptions, like "if full stop is preceded by 1-3 letters and first letter is a capital, ignore it"

Comment: "Don't tell that to my friend Jon.  He won't like it."

Comment: Please check my code above. Any idea?

Comment: Since *Mr* is [a full-word abbreviation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/101395/1696), it shouldn't be followed by a full stop in British English anyway.

Comment: There is a lot of returns with this function..

Answer (score 3):

Not to discourage you, but this is effectively impossible.  Consider the following sentence:

> The Griffins live on Spooner St. and the Simpsons live on Evergreen St.

Unless you are willing to depend on ever more unreliable indicia like capitalization, you have to admit the only way you can tell the second period marks both an end of an abbreviate and an end of a sentence, while the first marks only the first would be with full-scale syntactic analysis, something that's not really possible with a natural language.

(Yes, I know the Simpsons live on Evergreen *Terrace* but I wanted to illustrate the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could not use a dictionary, rather an array.

```
function SplitAtSentance($Criteria,$Word){
    $Word = explode (" ",$Word);
    foreach ($Criteria AS $Keys => $Values){
        if (in_array($Values,$Word)){
            $New = implode(" ",$Word);
            return str_replace($Values, $Values."<br>",$New);
        }
    }
    return false;

}

$Array = array ("Mr","ms");
$Original = "Mr Daryl";

echo SplitAtSentance($Array,$Original);
```

---

Heres is my current setup:

```
$Contents = file_get_contents("../test.txt");
function SplitAtSentance($Criteria,$Word){
$Word = explode (" ",$Word);
foreach ($Criteria AS $Keys => $Values){
    if (in_array($Values,$Word)){
        $New = implode(" ",$Word);
        return str_replace($Values, $Values."<br>",$New);
    }
}
return false;

}

$Contents = explode(",",$Contents);
$Sentance = "Dear mr Gill";
echo SplitAtSentance($Contents,$Sentance);
```

and the File Structure: 
 HTDOCS/TextDoc (Where the snippet is located) 
 HTDOCS (where text.txt is located)

the `../` will go back a directory and load the text document which contains:

> mr,sir,master,doc,doctor,PHD

Comment: thanks but this is similar to my own code, and it still needs to add a lot of words manually.

Comment: How else would you consider doing this? PHP is unaware of any spoken/written language, it wont act on anything unless it's told to act

Comment: well, here is the point of smart programming. I still believe that this problem can be solved by some kind of smart regex patterns. but how, I don't know yet!

Comment: @user2957386 Your looking for a regular expression which will match a wide range of words, this is not an answer, rather a brain ache. Store all these words in a text file/database/array and work from there.. It also offers the ability for the criteria to be expanded at any point, just by adding another element into whatever storage option you have selected.. Rather having to create a new regular expression/series of expressions to match the new criteria.

Comment: this is kind of useless. For example, I then need to fill up the array with thousands of words like '2:00', '20:00', '200:000', and so on!

Comment: Even using regexp pattern you need a list of words and runs more slowly. Also make your own dictionary but don't write the word list on bussines code. Include a PHP file returning array (like kohana config files) or read a plain text file.

Comment: @user2957386 For example purposes on my source safe server, we have a stored script which performs the exact same thing you are requiring to do, I have simply expanded the text file as necessary (perhaps taking a long time, if this is a worth while application then its resource effective).. Every criteria is commar seperated and we're on the verge of 10,000 individual specifications.Only with large things like this, will you need to consider the resources, Regular expressions run more slowly than seeking through an array.

Comment: Thanks @DarylGill . Do you know any text file or database that is publicly available?

Comment: @user2957386 None to my knowledge, because every site/project has it's own necessary requirements, it's best to just create the text file and expand it as necessary.. Since your project looks to be un-finished and in early development, it's about the right time to start the file.. Just gonna run down the shops & then if I come back to a reply that you are considering using the text file option, then I will post an example of how our current setup is

Comment: I believe the proverb about wanting to use a Regex and thereby having two problems applies here. @user Some problems cannot be solved by a Regex. This is one of them.

Comment: @DarylGill thanks! I am looking forward to seeing your example.

Comment: @user2957386 Sorry for the delay, notification did not come through, i'll get to work with re-post

Comment: @user2957386 Have a look at how i've got the setup